# What is a polymorphic reference of the Map Interface?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Map interface in a polymorphic reference

Is this an example of using the Map interface in a polymorphic reference?

```
//some code here

Map<String, List<String>> adtDictionary;

//some code here

adtDictionary = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

           while (departmentScanner.hasNextLine()) {
               String department = departmentScanner.nextLine().trim();
               adtDictionary.put(department, new ArrayList<String>());
           }

           while (facultyScanner.hasNextLine()) {
               String faculty = facultyScanner.nextLine();
               String[] values = faculty.split(",");
               adtDictionary.get(values[1].trim()).add(values[0]);
           }
//some code here
```

Comment: Do you have any more context for that question?

Comment: I actually tried asking a question on this earlier, but wasn't sure if I added too much information.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227693/does-this-contain-polymorphic-references-if-not-how-could-it-be-implemented

Comment: My interpretation of a 'polymorphic reference' would be a reference to a Map in a context where the try parameters were unimportant. For instance, a function to return the number of entries in a Map works on all Map instances. Your references would then *not* be polymorphic.

Comment: I was tasked with writing a program using the map interface in a polymorphic reference, and I don't quite understand what that means.

Comment: Just by looking it over, would you say it's possible to fix that?

Comment: Is the only requirement you were given "use a polymorphic reference"? It would be better if your instructor gave you a task which can only be solved by using polymorphic references.

Comment: There are more instructions. "For this assignment you are to write a program using the Map interface in a polymorphic reference with any of
your chosen already-defined classes that implement the interface to satisfy the requirements of this
assignment.
As you know, the ADT Dictionary (or Map) allows you to create a collection of key/value pairs. For this program,
you will read in data from two files:" basically i am just reading in and editing files of faculty names and departments

Comment: You could write a function which takes a Map of type Map<K,List<T>> and returns the key of the entry with the longest List. I think that might qualify. (so in your case it would be finding the largest department)